# How to minimize the time complexity of the following algo?

Tags: swift, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

There is a list of names like
ex). names = ["tom", "john", "tommy", "steve" ... ] which could be as big as 10^4 entries

- each name could be as short as a single character and as long as 18 letters.

I am required to return true or false of whether at least one of the name is the same to another name or a part of another name.

My solution using swift was like the following :

```
for index in names.indices{
     for index2 in names.indices{
         if names[index2].contains(names[index]) && (index != index2 ){
         return true
      }
    }
}

return false
```

But, as I have to iterate two 10^4 size for-loop, thus 10^8, and
within double for-loops, I have to use String.contains(other String) which has O(n) complexity, which is consistent to the size of the String which the method is applied to.

How can I minimize the "Time Complexity" by using other smarter strategies ?

Comment: A [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) could help.

Comment: Oh thanks I will look for that  

Comment: The "or a part of another name" makes it difficult. Is there any further restriction like must appear at the beginning?

Comment: Thank you for reply, Henry. Unfortunately not. It could be anywhere ... as in, the tommy contains tom in the front and bottom contains it at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A name with at most 18 characters can have at most 171 (=19*18/2) non-empty substrings, including the string itself. You could compute all these substrings and put them into a hash table. Then do a second pass through the list and check if any name is in the table.

This gives a total effort of O(n) where n is the length of the list. The constant factor is pretty high, but this is irrelevant for the asymptotic complexity.

Alternatively you can do it the other way round, put all the names into the hash table and then in a second path check if any substring of a name is in the table. This uses much less memory and has the same time complexity.